# Flutter bloc Bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bloc

what is the best way to run the timer in botom navigation bar with bloc and navigate to pages with out affecting the timer state

i am using bottom navigation bar in flutter with bloc , in each items in the bottom navigation bar having its own bloc. the problem is, in the first page am running a timer  and it get reseted while navigate to another page in BNB

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code example of your issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for this issue. Choose one that you prefer.

1. Add additional bloc which is watched by all bottom nav items, which will not be disposed even if bottom nav index has changed.
2. Use `IndexedStack` to preserve states.

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: IndexedStack(
    index: _currentIndex,
    children: _routes.map((route) => route.page).toList(),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    currentIndex: _currentIndex,
    onTap: _onPageChanged,
    items: _routes.map((route) {
      return BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: route.icon, label: route.name);
    }).toList(),
  ),
)
```